# Passing vectors of derived shared pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, vector

What is the proper way to allow vectors of shared pointers to a derived class to get passed to a function which is expecting a vector of shared pointers to a base class without performing a copy?

Here is the code:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class Base {
public:
    std::string Name;
};
using BaseList = std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Base>>;

class Derived : Base {
};
using DerivedList = std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Derived>>;

class BaseHandler {
public:
    void process( BaseList list ) {
    }
};

int main() {

    DerivedList list;

    BaseHandler bh;
    bh.process( list );

}
```

Code Link: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5a5b18ba3b2a4f08

EDIT: DOH!!!  I posted the wrong one.   Sorry about that...here is the shared_ptr one.

Comment: There is no way, proper or otherwise.

Comment: Copy of what? Of `std::shared_ptr`? It's not such a big deal copying them (their shared state is not being deep copied btw).

Comment: Note that: vector<Base> is not base class of vector<Derived>.

Comment: Ahhh....right!   So, do I have to iterate through them and copy them to a new vector in order to do this?

Comment: Kinda sucks if so. I'd like to know this too. But I think you can't do better.

Answer (score 2):

You may try this.

```
template <class T,
        class SharedPtr = typename T::value_type,
        class Element = typename SharedPtr::element_type,
        class IsDerived = typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Base, Element>::value, void*>::type
    >
void process(const T& t) { std::cout << "process" << std::endl; }
```

The key ideas are:

1. Instead of accessing the elements through base class pointers, we can access the them through their concrete type information known by the compiler.
2. This function template uses a trick called "SFINAE" to check whether the parameter is a container of smart pointer of derived class.

---

---

**Follow up**:

Conversion from "container of shared pointer to derived class" to "container of shared pointer to base class" is possible and not very difficult. However, I concern whether the design choice of using "container of shared pointer to base class" will give you acceptable performance.

---

Let's discuss how to do it first.

1. We can create a `std::shared_ptr<Base>` object from each `std::shared_ptr<Derived>` object by using `std::static_pointer_cast`.
2. To apply `std::static_pointer_cast` on everything entries of the list, we can use `std::transform`.
3. If you have many derived classes, the conversion can be made available to every derived classes by using a function template with SFINAE check as mentioned.

So, the code looks like:

```
DerivedList derivedList;
// Put items into derivedList

BaseList baseList;
baseList.reserve(derivedList.size());
std::transform(std::begin(derivedList), std::end(derivedList), std::back_inserter(baseList),
    [](const std::shared_ptr<Derived>& shptr)
    {
        return std::static_pointer_cast<Base>(shptr);
    });

BaseHandler bh;
bh.process(baseList);
```

Or:

```
class BaseForwarder
{
public:
    template <class T,
            class SharedPtr = typename T::value_type,
            class Element = typename SharedPtr::element_type,
            class IsDerived = typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Base, Element>::value, void*>::type
        >
    void process(const T& derivedList)
    {
        BaseList baseList;
        baseList.reserve(derivedList.size());

        std::transform(std::begin(derivedList), std::end(derivedList), std::back_inserter(baseList),
                [](const SharedPtr& shptr)
                {
                    return std::static_pointer_cast<Base>(shptr);
                });

        BaseHandler bh;
        bh.process(baseList);
    }
};
```

---

However, this approach has quite a lot of performance penalty.

- A new list of pointer to base class has to be created for each list of pointer to derived class. It spends a lot of time and memory to construct the new list.
- The objects are accessed through pointers. This indirection slow things down.
- Since the objects are not allocated into compact data structure, cache misses will be severe.

I suggest you to evaluate the performance to see whether this approach is acceptable. Otherwise, it is better to consider some other design choices.

Comment: I find this very interesting....however, it doesn't actually convert it to the shared_ptr of base class, so this now forces the implementation of "process" to be placed in the header file (something I want to avoid).    I was kind of goofing around with it here http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/571ec96419f8224d and it passes it still as `std::vector<shared_ptr<Derived>>`    In my case, I am dealing with potentially 100s of millions of members in this vector, and I really want to avoid copying them.   I would use the actual base class, but I need just a few extra properties on them.

Comment: @user3072517 I have extended the answer as a response.

Comment: It looks like there is not much way around having to make the copy if I want to keep the inheritance.   This seems such a shame that it cannot be done without such a performance hit.    To better understand why it is being asked is because these vectors hold all the fields in every record from a result set of a query.   The derived versions of these contain an 'Is Modified' flag.  They are created as a derived set, but I now need to load them with the response from the database. That load happens on the base class, and I would rather not repeat the load logic on the derived class.

Comment: With type and pointer safety, comes a flexibility penalty as well.

Comment: @user3072517 You may raise another question to look for alternative design choices by mentioning the concrete problem underlying this question. But for now, this is the best I can do.